# Creating a sequential list of dates from a set start date to the latest end date

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I've a macro that is unusably slow. How could I speed it up/replace it with something better?

I have up to 20 potential different end dates, and I want to populate a sequential list of dates from a set start date, to the latest end date.

```vb
Sub DateAutoFill()
    Dim StartD As Date, EndD As Date
    StartD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("B55")
    If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AN60")) Then
        EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AN60")
    Else
        If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AL60")) Then
            EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AL60")
        Else
            If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AJ60")) Then
                EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AJ60")
            Else
                If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AH60")) Then
                    EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AH60")
                Else
                    If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AF60")) Then
                        EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AF60")
                    Else
                        If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AD60")) Then
                            EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AD60")
                        Else
                            If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AB60")) Then
                                EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AB60")
                            Else
                                If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("Z60")) Then
                                    EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("Z60")
                                Else
                                    If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("X60")) Then
                                        EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("X60")
                                    Else
                                        If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("V60")) Then
                                            EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("V60")
                                        Else
                                            If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("T60")) Then
                                                EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("T60")
                                            Else
                                                If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("R60")) Then
                                                    EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("R60")
                                                Else
                                                    If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("P60")) Then
                                                        EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("P60")
                                                    Else
                                                        If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("N60")) Then
                                                            EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("N60")
                                                        Else
                                                            If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("L60")) Then
                                                                EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("L60")
                                                            Else
                                                                If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("J60")) Then
                                                                    EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("J60")
                                                                Else
                                                                    If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("H60")) Then
                                                                        EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("H60")
                                                                    Else
                                                                        If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("FD60")) Then
                                                                            EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("F60")
                                                                        Else
                                                                            If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("D60")) Then
                                                                                EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("D60")
                                                                            Else
                                                                                If IsDate(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("B60")) Then
                                                                                    EndD = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("B60")
                                                                                Else
                                                                                    MsgBox "Enter Investment Period Section on Calculator Sheet"
                                                                                End If
                                                                            End If
                                                                        End If
                                                                    End If
                                                                End If
                                                            End If
                                                        End If
                                                    End If
                                                End If
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    For Row = 1 To EndD - StartD
        Cells(Row, 44) = StartD + Row - 1
    Next Row
End Sub
```

I am hoping to get something that is equivalent to drag and drop, or a simple A1+1 formula, that can end at the oldest end date of up to 20 dates.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired output?

Comment: Your `If..End If` statements can be replaced to make things far more readable, but you state the reason for the question is that the code is ***too slow***? Do you know which part is running slow

Comment: @CLR- thanks for responding!

When I execute the macro, the process of auto-filling the dates into the column, takes a long time and freezes excel with the loading blue circle. I doubt it is hardware limited, as I'm fortunate enough to be using an Alienware M15 R3.

Comment: @jsheeran - Thanks for responding. Once my excel unfreezes, I'll post some screenshots of the sample data, and then the desired output.

Comment: All good! I've broken it down using formula. I just used MAX to find the largest value of the range of dates, then used DAYS to calculate number of days, then used SEQUENCE to self populate. It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

**(1)** Don't repeat your worksheet-name over and over again, use a With clause instead.

**(2)** There is an `ElseIf`-statement in VBA, if you use that, it makes the code already more readable

**(3)** It seems that you are checking every second column, starting from `AN` (that's column number 40) back to `B` (2). You could use a loop to check for the end date.

```
Dim StartD As Date, EndD as Date
With Worksheets("Calculator")
    StartD = .Range("B55") 
    Dim col As Long
    For col = 40 to 2 step -2    ' Look at every 2nd col, starting at AN (=40)
       If IsDate(.Cells(60, col)) Then
           EndD = .Cells(60, col)
           Exit For
       End If
    Next
End With

If EndD = 0 Then 
   MsgBox ...
Else
   ...
End If
```

Comment: This is so much nicer! Thank you, much more to learn.

However, it still takes a long time for the Macro to actually execute. When I run this macro, it still renders Excel unusable, with the blue loading circle (it's been 5 minutes and still going).

I doubt it is hardware limited, as I'm fortunate enough to be using an Alienware M15 R3. And it doesn't seem like that difficult of a thing for it to do?

Comment: All good! I've broken it down using formula. I just used MAX to find the largest value of the range of dates, then used DAYS to calculate number of days, then used SEQUENCE to self populate. It's working perfectly.

Comment: Very nice!   I didn't see the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to make the code ore readable.

### `If ElseIf Else`

```
Sub DateAutoFill()
    Dim StartD As Date, EndD As Date
    
    With Worksheets("Calculator")
        StartD = .Range("B55")
        If IsDate(.Range("AN60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("AN60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("AL60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("AL60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("AJ60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("AJ60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("AH60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("AH60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("AF60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("AF60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("AD60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("AD60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("AB60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("AB60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("Z60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("Z60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("X60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("X60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("V60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("V60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("T60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("T60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("R60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("R60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("P60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("P60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("N60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("N60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("L60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("L60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("J60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("J60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("H60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("H60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("FD60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("F60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("D60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("D60")
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("B60")) Then
            EndD = .Range("B60")
        Else
            MsgBox "Enter Investment Period Section on Calculator Sheet"
        End If
    End With
    
    For Row = 1 To EndD - StartD
        Cells(Row, 44) = StartD + Row - 1
    Next Row
End Sub
```

### `Select Case`

```
Sub DateAutoFill()
    Dim StartD As Date, EndD As Date
        
    With Worksheets("Calculator")
        StartD = .Range("B55")
            
        Select Case True
            Case IsDate(.Range("AN60"))
                EndD = .Range("AN60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("AL60"))
                EndD = .Range("AL60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("AJ60"))
                EndD = .Range("AJ60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("AH60"))
                EndD = .Range("AH60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("AF60"))
                EndD = .Range("AF60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("AD60"))
                EndD = .Range("AD60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("AB60"))
                EndD = .Range("AB60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("Z60"))
                EndD = .Range("Z60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("X60"))
                EndD = .Range("X60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("V60"))
                EndD = .Range("V60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("T60"))
                EndD = .Range("T60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("R60"))
                EndD = .Range("R60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("P60"))
                EndD = .Range("P60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("N60"))
                EndD = .Range("N60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("L60"))
                EndD = .Range("L60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("J60"))
                EndD = .Range("J60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("H60"))
                EndD = .Range("H60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("FD60"))
                EndD = .Range("F60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("D60"))
                EndD = .Range("D60")
            Case IsDate(.Range("B60"))
                EndD = .Range("B60")
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Enter Investment Period Section on Calculator Sheet"
        End Select
    End With
        
    For Row = 1 To EndD - StartD
        Cells(Row, 44) = StartD + Row - 1
    Next Row
End Sub
```